# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host ' ' (2) in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Hi I am making a simple login in laravel and I get an error when I try to perform an authentication. It is a rather odd connection error

[image]

**Conection**

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'Marsur',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'options'   => array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        ),
    ),
```

**Controller**

```
public function doLogin(){
    $rules = array('correo' => 'required|email',
                    'password' => 'required');

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('usuario')
                ->withErrors($validator)// manda los errores al login
                ->withInput(Input::except('password')); //

    }else{
        $userData = array(
                    'Correo' => Input::get('correo'),
                    'Contrasena' => Input::get('password')
                    );

        if(Auth::attempt($userData)){
            echo 'bien';
        }else{
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
}
```

**Model***

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Usuario';
protected $primaryKey = 'idUsuario';
protected $fillable = array('Nombre', 
                        'Apellido', 
                        'TipoUsuario', 
                        'Contrasena', 
                        'Correo', 
                        'Telefono');
}
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marsur` is almost certainly not a valid hostname.

Generally a hostname is an IP address, or `localhost`. On some occasions you may refer to a remote server by its hostname, but in such a case it will have a name that looks like a web address.

So... fix that. If your database is on the same physical machine as the rest of your code, then you need `localhost`.

Comment: True that, I dont know why change that config. Thank, but know apper that error ``SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Marsur.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `Correo` = marcelo@twable.com and `Contrasena` = 1234 limit 1)`` I need use the Usuario model and not User class :S

Comment: Are you using the correct database name and table name?

Comment: `` 'host'      => 'localhost','database'  => 'Marsur', ``.Where can I choose the table name Usuario ?

Comment: I don't know, but generally speaking you should always name things in English anyway. If it's expecting `users`, give it `users`.