# Laravel 5.1: migrate command doesn't work 'unknown database'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm facing problems with my laravel project built with laravel 5.1.

So I developed a reservation system with laravel, it works on my local server.

Then I uploaded it  to my live server and started an SSH session.

But when I ran `php artisan migrate` command, I get this error:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'sddb0040291787.cgidb' (0)

So, what I did so far is I wrote a PHP script to create the tables and other database related stuff and then run the PHP script on my server.

This works actually, my CRUD functions are working but I know this is just a temporary solution.

What I'm looking for is a permanent solution. Plain PHP scripts seem to be able to connect to the database host. but when I migrate using laravel, the error always shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the .env file contain correct Host, Username, Password, Database Name parameters?

Comment: yes. I also changed the values on the database.php file as well. then ran `php artisan config:cache` command

Answer (score 1):

check your `.env` or `database.php` you have

```
'host'      => 'sddb0040291787.cgidb'
```

which is not validname it should be `localhost` or any domain name which will look like a webaddress or it should be an IP.

Also refer: Similar questions on SO: 
[REF1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138414/sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-2-in-laravel) &
[REF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193554/i-have-the-error-sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host)

Hope it will help.

Comment: I just referred to my hosting's MySQL configuration and they gave that host name.